# simple print a circle GUI issues

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I am new to gui stuff and I want to make a simple program to print a circle to represent the sun, and then near it I want to print another circle to represent a planet. My issue is when I added the method paintPlanet, all that is returned in the gui window is blank screen now. Even when I commented paintPlanet out, the circle for the sun will not print and I am left with a blank window. Can someone help me figure out where I went wrong how to fix it so both circles will print? I am new to GUI things so be easy on me :)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class PlanetsLogic extends JPanel
{   
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void paintSun(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    //create circle and fill it as yellow to represent the sun
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.drawOval(100, 75, 75, 75);
    g.fillOval(100, 75, 75, 75);
} //end paintSun


public void paintPlanet(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //create circle and fill it as yellow to represent the orbiting planet
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawOval(75, 75, 75, 75);
    g.fillOval(75, 75, 75, 75);


}//end paintPlanet

}//end class PlanetsLogic
```

MAIN:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class OrbitingPlants_main 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    PlanetsLogic planet = new PlanetsLogic();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setTitle("Orbiting Planets");
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(planet); //add panel onto frame
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your paintSun and paintPlanet methods will never be magically called. Instead your JPanel needs to override the paintComponent method as all drawing is done there. You can even call your paintSun and paintPlanet methods from within paintComponent, but I would recommend calling the `super.paintComponent(g)` only once and only from within your paintComponent method override itself.

e.g.,

```
// use @Override to ask the compiler to check if this method is a true override
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); // HERE!
    paintSun(g);
    paintPlanet(g);
}

public void paintSun(Graphics g) {
    // super.paintComponent(g); // nope, not here!

    //create circle and fill it as yellow to represent the sun
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.drawOval(100, 75, 75, 75);
    g.fillOval(100, 75, 75, 75);
} //end paintSun


public void paintPlanet(Graphics g) {
    // super.paintComponent(g);  // NO don't call this here
    //create circle and fill it as yellow to represent the orbiting planet
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawOval(75, 75, 75, 75);
    g.fillOval(75, 75, 75, 75);
}//end paintPlanet
```

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid that I didn't catch that. Thank you!!